# Redirecting into my Laravel project folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have the following content in my `.htaccess` file. I expected it to redirect to my project folder `/hc` which is at the same level as `.htaccess`. The redirection is not happening and it is still displaying the contents of `index.html`.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /hc/

<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

> I expected it to redirect to my project folder `/hc` which is **at the same level as `.htaccess`**.

That's the problem. If the `.htaccess` file is in the `/hc` subdirectory then it's never going to see the request unless you already include the `/hc` subdirectory on the request.

Your `.htaccess` file needs to go in the parent directory. ie. the document root. (Incidentally, you would only need the `RewriteBase /hc/` directive if this file was in the document root.)

Or, include an *additional* `.htaccess` file in the document root that simply forwards all requests to your `/hc` directory (your front controller), for example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) hc/$1 [L]
```

Note that since mod_rewrite is not inherited by default, once the request is rewritten to the `/hc` subdirectory, the `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory is then processed and overrides the mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file, so you don't end up with a rewrite loop.

---

> ```
> RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L,QSA]
> ```

**UPDATE:** Your *substitution* string in the last `RewriteRule` differs from the earlier directive. Both are probably not correct. You may want to remove the `?` in the above directive, unless you intend to us the query string, then you should add a `?` to the earlier directive. As it stands, the first uses *path information* to pass the URL, the second uses the *query string*.

Incidentally, the `PT` flag is redundant in per-directory `.htaccess` files. And if you aren't using the query string, then the `QSA` flag can be removed also.

Comment: I have put the .htaccess in my parent (public_html) still no success.

Answer (score 0):

You need to let "rewrite" option in your "sites-available" apache config file. For laravel you should be careful because your DocumentRoot  (public folder where you need .htaccess file) is inside project folder .